# Finding parametric equations and an equation in vector form

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem asks: Find parametric equations and an equation in vector form for the line in $R^{2}$ with the equation: $y = 3x -1$

vector form is $x = p + td$ where $p$ and $d$ are vectors and $t$ is a scalar. To find $p$ I pick a number for $x$ and plug into the equation to get the corresponding $y$. So $x = 0$ gives $y = -1$, so $p = [0, -1]$ because 3 is the scalar multiplied with $x$ and 1 is the scalar multiplied with $y$, I thought the vector form would be:

$$
   \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + t 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
           3 \\ 
           1 \\ 
           \end{bmatrix}
$$

and from the vector form the parametric form follows easily, so I'm going to skip writing it. This however is wrong since the answer sheet gives the correct answer with $3$ going to y and 1 going to $x$:

$$
   \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           -1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + t 
    \begin{bmatrix} 
           1 \\ 
           3 \\ 
           \end{bmatrix}
$$

I don't understand why that's so, could someone please explain. Also, where does the -1 go in $y = 3x -1$, how come it isn't represented in any of those forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for an intuitive approach as to why the answer sheet's answer is right, note that the line $y = 3x - 1$ has slope 3. Your equation parametrizes a line that has slope 1/3, since if you let $t$ vary from 0 to 1, say, $x$ varies from 0 to 3, while $y$ varies only from -1 to 0; this is a line of slop 1/3, not of slope 3.

The answer key equation gives a line that, as $t$ varies from 0 to 1 (say), has $x$ vary from 0 to 1 and $y$ vary from -1 to 2, which is the correct slope of 3.

The directional vector $d$ should be the slope vector; if the slope, for instance is 3 (as it is in this case), any vector that has slope 3 will do. So just pick the vector 
$$
d = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
3
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

As for the -1, note that at $x = 0$, we have $y = 3\cdot 0 - 1 = -1$. This is captured in the vector form of the equation by the *initial position* vector 
$$
p = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because look what happens when we put $t = 0$ in the vector equation; we get $(x, y) = (0, -1) + 0\cdot d = (0, -1)$, meaning that the point $(0, -1)$ is on our line, as it should be. Really, it just serves as a convenient starting point to draw the vector equation line from.

Comment: so can $x$ in $d$ be any number? for example $d=[5,3]$

Comment: @FakeBrain not exactly - it can be any vector that has slope 3. This [5, 3] would not work, then, since it has slop 5/3, not 3. Any SCALAR multiple of [1, 3] would work, for instance [2, 6].

Comment: The vector $d$ should be thought of as follows: start at the point $p$. Then draw a line in the direction that the "arrow" $d$ points in.

Answer (score 0):

For a one variable function $f(x)$ we can parameterize its graph by setting $x=t, y=f(t)$ so using column vectors we have

$\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           t \\
           3t-1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} t\\ 3t\\ \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ -1\\ \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 3\\ \end{bmatrix} t + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ -1\\ \end{bmatrix} $